# Can I have Excel create new rows instead of throwing a SPILL error?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

If an equation returns multiple results, it will attempt to write the output to multiple cells. However, a SPILL error is thrown if there are non-blank cells that would be overwritten.

Is it possible to have excel just create new rows to avoid the SPILL error? I would ideally just like to shift all the cells down.

Comment: Short answer: 'No' Formulas cannot do that.

Comment: Rather than insert rows, you could hide enough rows to allow for the maximum return and then have them hide or unhide using a change event macro? If you think that might work I can write something up.

Comment: @JustinDoward Don't worry about it. I've decided it's not worth the effort. If I see a SPILL error I just have to manually add rows.